# Unexpected Error on UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, servicenow

I'm trying to call my ServiceNow JSON web service.  I'm getting an unexpected error when I execute URLFetchApp.  I'm guessing I'm passing in the authorization headers in the wrong way but both the GAS and ServiceNow documentation is beyond terrible.  I've seen some of the other SO questions similar to this but none have worked.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
function getOpenTickets(){
    var headers = {
    "Authorization":"Basic RgRJ5U6EsxHt00229KX5Hj0WV1z18q08==",
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    "Username":"myusername",
    "Password":"mypassword"
}
var url = "https://mysninstance.service-now.com/u_equipment_repair.do?JSONv2=&sysparm_view=vendor&displayvalue=true&sysparm_action=getRecords&sysparm_query=state=500^assignment_group.name=MyGroup^ORDERBYDESCnumber";
var url = encodeURIComponent(url);
var options = {
  "method":"get",
  "headers":headers
}
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
Logger.log(result.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a particular error message? If not, are you getting any response at all? That would help determine what's going on with you.

Comment: All I get is the error "Unexpected Error" with the url I tried to call appended to it. Here go the details of the message: Unexpected error: http://https%3A%2F%2Fmysninstance.service-now.com%2Fu_equipment_repair.do%3FJSONv2%3D%26sysparm_view%3Dvendor%26displayvalue%3Dtrue%26sysparm_action%3DgetRecords%26sysparm_query%3Dstate%3D500%5Eassignment_group.name%3DBoscop%5EORDERBYDESCnumber (line 17, file "Code")

Comment: The Apps Script team has recently completed several internal changes that should significantly reduce the number of timeout and 'unexpected' errors caused when running UrlFetch from a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

OK so I found the solution.  There were actually two problems.

The first was with the way I was passing the authorization headers.  I was passing the basic authentication as an already encoded base64 string, on top of which I was still passing the username and password which was redundant.  For whatever reason Google Apps Script (GAS) doesn't like this.  Once I changed the headers and the options as shown below it was fine.

The second problem was the the URI encoding.  The query string did need to be encoded because of the caret "^" symbols, but for whatever reason GAS's encodeURIComponent was not encoding it properly.  As soon as I manually replaced the caret symbols with their URL encoded equivalents , which is "%5E", everything worked fine and I was able to retrieve my ServiceNow data via Google Apps Script.

```
function getOpenTickets3(){
  var headers =
  {
Authorization : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode('myusername:mypassword'),
"Content-Type":"application/json"
  }

  var options =
  {
"method" : "get",
"headers": headers
  };

 var url = "https://mysninstance.service-now.com/u_equipment_repair.do?JSONv2=&sysparm_view=vendor&displayvalue=true&sysparm_action=getRecords&sysparm_query=state=500%5Eassignment_group.name=Somevendor%5EORDERBYDESCnumber";
 var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
 Logger.log(result.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: It works well ! Using your approach I was able to manage the Transifex API calls with GAS.

Answer (score 0):

You are URI encoding your entire URL in this line:

```
var url = encodeURIComponent(url);
```

In your URL, the base path needs to be unescaped when passed to `fetch(...)`:

```
https://mysninstance.service-now.com/u_equipment_repair.do
```

Each parameter following the `?` is a URI component, like:

```
sysparm_view=vendor
```

In this case, the parameter name is `sysparm_view` and the value is `vendor`, you would need to URI encode the value (`vendor`) if it contained special characters like one of `/?&`.
In the static URL you provide, there's actually nothing that needs to be encoded, so removing that call to `encodeURIComponent(url)` should work.

If you are dealing with dynamic values for your URL parameters, then you'd want to URI encode each parameter value separately, before concatenating onto the main string.